# Resume git p4 clone migration after failure

Tags: git, migration, perforce

We need to migrate dozens of perforce repositories to git. We do not have license for git fusion, so we are working with git-p4. My main concern is that in order to access P4, we need to be connected to VPN, which is not very stable to say the least. VPN connection hangs several times per day and so does git p4 migrations. I was unable to find any documentation/info how to resume existing p4 migration, is it even possible?

Thanks

Comment: Can you run your command on a computer which is in the main data center and does not need to go through the VPN?